# Starting with facebook app (need guidelines)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to make a facebook app, to make draws (like raffles) between the users who like my fan page, or eventually who likes a post.
I've been developing another app which do other stuff, but i'm stuck with this and it's really frustrating to not be able to do something so simple as this.

In the first place, i wish to make it available in a page tab (and that users doesn't need to "install" the app. Maybe this isn't needed if the user is just "looking" at a page that is loaded in my hosting)

Second, i don't know how could i get (assuming the one who enters the app/page tab is an admin) all the users who liked the page/post without using an access_token (because this damn access_token has an expiration time, and if i could, i'd try not to use an access token at all, since i assume the user who gets in into some parts is an admin

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make an app that draws a contest winner from the people who like your page. Facebook does not allow you to query the fans of your pages anymore.

You can still query the users who like a post on your page though so you should set your contest up this way.

To get started, you'll need to create a connector app for your page. Users don't need to register for this app. As long as they like your page, your app will be able to access their public data. Your app will have an API key and secret. Using these, you'll be able to access information about your page.

To find a user who liked a post, you can query this with a variety of languages. I'm not sure which one you are using, so I'll give you instructions to do this from the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Make your post on a page, and type `PAGE_ID_OR_USERNAME/feed` where you replace PAGE_ID_OR_USERNAME with your page's id or username. Find the id of the post you just listed in there. It will look something like this: `213365490637345_40261112079719` (not a real post_id)

Now you can get all the user ids of people who liked that post by typing this into the explorer box:

```
  fql?q=SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = "213365490637345_40261112079719"
```

And then choose a random id from that list and contact that particular user. You may have to use Facebook as your page when you try to contact them.